# Is it safe to clean obj file inside project manually?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

My object file contains debug,release folder and some other files. My object file is about 1gb. Is it safe to clean it manually? If i will click clean in my project it doesn't remove everything inside my debug folder. That's why i want to make it manually

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

Comment: Well, how about you try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can purge everything in the `bin` and `obj` folders and they will get recreated when you build.

Comment: Thank you Jason. So if i will delete entire obj folder? Am i ok?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the obj folder content manually but if you are working with large projects deleting obj content will build everything from scratch hence increasing the compilation time. obj folder is used for conditional compiling.

Comment: This will happen only once? Or in each build?

Comment: in each build it tries conditional compilation

Comment: So should i delete or not obj folder? Is it safe?

Comment: it is safe. i just described the cons so that you know what really happens internally.